# Python requests library - the difference between is_permanent_redirect and is_redirect for marking an URL as inactive

Tags: python, python-3.x, get, python-requests

I want to understand whether an URL is inactive or not.

For this task, I will be using the `requests` library. I will use different markers for understanding URL is inactive or not.

One from markers will be `redirects`.

If the inactive website does a redirect for another website it's mean the website is inactive.

I want to use for this `is_permanent_redirect` or `is_redirect` in `requests` library.

What needs for my task `is_permanent_redirect` or `is_redirect`?

How can I write better code for this task using `is_permanent_redirect` or `is_redirect`?

Comment: If the redirect is permanent, then you should forget the original URL and use the new redirected-to URL. If it's just a redirect, the original URL is still valid and you should continue querying it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python requests library has the following options:

- Handle default Redirects
- Fetch redirects and figure out the change needed

For handling of redirect manually, we need to use the following property: `allow_redirects=False`

For example:

```
>>>import requests
>>> r = requests.get('http://github.com/', allow_redirects=False )
>>> r.is_redirect
True
>>> r.is_permanent_redirect
True
```

Coming to the difference between `is_permanent_redirect` and `is_redirect`, by their code, I can see the following checks:

[is_redirect](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/428f7a275914f60a8f1e76a7d69516d617433d30/requests/models.py#L713): This checks all the 3xx [status codes](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/428f7a275914f60a8f1e76a7d69516d617433d30/requests/models.py#L47) like

```
codes.moved,               # 301
codes.found,               # 302
codes.other,               # 303
codes.temporary_redirect,  # 307
codes.permanent_redirect,  # 308
```

[is_permanent_redirect](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/428f7a275914f60a8f1e76a7d69516d617433d30/requests/models.py#L720): This checks for only

```
codes.temporary_redirect,  # 307
codes.permanent_redirect,  # 308
```

This should give you more information about the actual 300 status codes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection

My suggestion is, if you use `is_redirect` for your use case, that should suffice to catch all moved URLs. This way you can look whether the URL is inactive. Yet it depends on your choice of when do you want to mark a URL as inactive.

Comment: Thank you very much for your great answer.